# Rearrange "DistributedAmount" field in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

In JOLT I am trying to rearrange distributed amount field. However, `itemTotalAmount` is getting sorted correctly in the output but `distributedAmount` is not.

Any idea what changes I need to make to the JOLT spec to get the `distributedAmount` field in the output?

**Link for Input and Spec**- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vvdFBPwaHRVvjttUTQP0jzQlqYlGfjFZ

Desired Output-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jolt spec file is about **490** lines!!!

**This answer is not a good answer.**

But I suggest you do all of your transformations and when it's done, see again your spec and try to **optimize your spec**. For example, In your case, you can merge some of your `shift` operations together.

The **simple** and **fastest** way to achieve your desired output is adding a new spec to your current spec.

Please add the below spec to your current spec:

```json
,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // IntegrationDetails
        "*": { // integrationEntities
          "*": { // integrationEntity
            "*": { // 0
              "integrationEntityHeader": "&4.&3.&2[&1].&",
              "integrationEntityDetails": {
                "*": { // poDetails
                  "*": "&6.&5.&4[&3].&2.&1.&",
                  "items": {
                    "item": {
                      "*": "&8.&7.&6[&5].&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                      "validCombinations": {
                        "*": { // itemDetails
                          "validRules": "&10.&9.&8[&7].&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                          "distributedAmount": "&10.&9.&8[&7].&6.&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```